# WatchConnectivity session in more than one view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-watch, watchos-2

I am developing a watch app using watchOS 2 and its parent app is on iOS 9 beta. I am using `WatchConnectivity` sessions to pass data from Apple Watch to iPhone. I need to have session in 2 different view controller files, so is there any problems to start new WCSessions in each of the view controllers and use them?

Basically I am trying to navigate from one view controller to other view controller using `performSegueWithIdentifier`, it works fine when I put it in `viewDidLoad`, but as soon as I put it inside session method, it starts breaking, and I am suspecting that it has to do something with WCSessions.

Following is the part of code in which I am trying to navigate:

```
- (void)session:(nonnull WCSession *)session didReceiveMessage:(nonnull NSDictionary *)message replyHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSDictionary * __nonnull replyMessage))replyHandler {
    NSString *msg = [message objectForKey:@"msg"];
    // NSDictionary* replyValues =  @{@"session":@"established between phone   and watch"};
    if ([msg isEqualToString:@"fromWatch"]) {
        isWatch = true;
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"startDashboardSegue" sender: self];
    }
    // NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    // [prefs setObject:messageFlag forKey:@"messageFlag"];

    //replyHandler(replyValues);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to dispatch back to the main queue to perform the segue?

Comment: Thanks.We have used dispatch back to main queue and its working :)

Comment: Hey @deepthitoopran. Can you show me how you did the dispatch back to main queue

Answer (score 1):

The comment above the WCSessionDelegate section in the WCSession header states:

> ----------------------------- WCSessionDelegate -----------------------------
>
> The session calls the delegate methods when content is received and session
>     state changes. All delegate methods will be called on the same queue. The
>     delegate queue is a non-main serial queue. It is the client's responsibility
>     to dispatch to another queue if neccessary.

so if you want to update the UI (and you are using UIKit) you will have to dispatch to the main queue before invoking the UI update methods.